# Using Android phone as wireless viewfinder for my Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, remote, wifi, self-portrait

I am thinking about buying a 1300D and taking some photos with it.

I am thinking of climbing to the Mount Sipylus and taking photos of myself just like the expedition photos of history (which always fascinated me during my childhood) instead of taking a selfie.

[Expedition Photograph](https://archaeologyarchivesoxford.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/men-with-pitchforks-scr1.jpg)

But the problem is I don't know how I will look when I take photos of myself! Will I fit to the frame or will it fit to the grid points?

So I want use the wifi function of the 1300D and get myself to the spot with my phone, giving me live feed of what the camera sees at my hand, and take a photo of myself.

Can my Android phone do that?

I saw some accessories that let you to plug your phone to the USB port, but that's not exactly what I want, although it's better than nothing...

Comment: I am not familiar with what's available from Canon, but I know that there's an [app from Fujifilm](https://www.fujifilm.eu/eu/news/article/fujifilm-launches-new-version-of-the-camera-remote-that-supports-all-fujifilm-wireless-equipped-digital-cameras) that allows you to do this.

Comment: i used to snap "test shots" that made it back to my big screen in order to do this a few years back. Video out can help if all you need is framing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your camera is supported by Canon Camera Connect (available for Android on the PlayStore), that can make your phone act as a remote Liveview monitor (among plenty of other things). CCC is free, so you can easily test that it fulfills your needs.

Remember to bring spare batteries (for the camera, and perhaps for the phone), because this kind of use, especially in very cold environments, tends to drain batteries rather quickly.